# Check for index key using an array in codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, composite-primary-key

I'm using codeigniter framework for my project. And I have a multidimensional array generated as follow.

```
<?php
     foreach ($tempResult->result() as $row) {
          $key[] = array( 
                     'date'=>$today,
                     'reg_id'=>$this->input->post("reg_id"),
                     'day'=>$row->day
                   );
     }
?>
```

This creates a data set as below.

> row 1 (2018/07/08,M1111,Monday)
>
> row 2 (2018/07/08,M1111,Tuesday)
>
> row 3 (2018/07/08,M1111,Thursday)

Above php code "date,reg_id,day" is the composite key of the db table.
I want to send the generated multi dimensional array to the db table and check if the key values are already exists.

I understand that using `$this->db->where($array);` can send a one dimensional array and check if the index exists. But here I don't understand and need to do is check for existence of multiple data sets as the key.

Comment: you should use `where_in` instead of `where` which takes an array as second parameters

Comment: You can use several `where`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generates a `where_in` (‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query joined with and if appropriate, this will work.

> $this->db->where_in('date', $date);

Comment: thnx. I figured it out